# Web site not working

Tags: website

We have problem our website is not working >it says `Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.srcollege.edu.in.`

Contacted the manashosting but in vain.

Can any one solve this problem

Comment: You should keep contacting your host/DNS provider. They are the only able to help

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons for this being the case.

1. The destination server is down
2. The DNS record(s) is not set or down
3. The web service is down on the server
4. Although the same answer as 2, you no longer own the domain and the DNS has been "reset"

A quick ping shows it doesn't respond and in FireFox it says DNS fail... This suggests that you cannot get to the site due to DNS more than anything else.

Log onto your control panel with your provider and verify the `A record` is pointing to the correct place.